# Problem with installing apache

Tags: php, apache-2.2, localhost

I get this when I install the apache on windows:

```
only one usage of each socket address
```

is normally permitted. :make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80

Note that I had visual studio 2010 installed on it..and developed an asp.net site on this pc using the local host...

Any way I can install the apache and run it without getting this:
http://localhost/

, when I type:

> Bad Request (Invalid Hostname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already running another web server on your machine, which is bound to port `80`.

Somewhere in your Apache config file, there will be a line that looks like this:

```
Listen 80
```

If you change it to this

```
Listen 8080
```

It will bind Apache to port `8080`, so you can access your Apache web sites like this:

http://localhost:8080/

Alternatively, you reconfigure Visual Studio to use a different HTTP port.

Comment: I could use it with netstat command (by what a read currently) to port 81... the appache has got a folder called conf.. // i changed listen 90 to 8080 ..still doesnt work.. i changed the text file named httpd to what you said

Comment: Edit..: correction..i changed this to : http://localhost:8081/ ...will this setting not make problem?!??

Comment: There is no reason why using any particular port should cause a problem, as long as another program doesn't try and use it as well. I often use `10080` on machines where one (or more) web servers is already installed.